# ajc wont compile lambda as an vararg argument

Tags: java, lambda, aspectj, java-8

I'm using ajc 1.8, java 8 and experiencing compiler issue. Here's the sample code.

```
 public class ExecutorTests {
    List<Runnable> tasks = Arrays.asList(
            () -> {
                System.out.println("task1 start");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ignored) {}
                System.out.println("task1 end");
            },
            () -> {
                System.out.println("task2 start");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ignored) {}
                System.out.println("task2 end");
            },
            () -> {
                System.out.println("task3 start");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ignored) {}
                System.out.println("task3 end");
            }
    );

    @Test
    public void executeInSync(){
        tasks.stream().forEach(Runnable::run);
    }
}
```

This code properly compiles and executes with javac meanwhile ajc fails with following :

[image]

If I replace lambdas with anonymous classes this will compile and run, but I'd like to find workaround that didnt force me to get back to anonymous classes, any vm arguments or any other workarounds?

My recent issue with java 8 code compilation issue with ajc were solved using -noverify flag.

Maybe I'll get rid of all issues using load time weaving?

Comment: One workaround might be to pull the lambda expressions out into their own `Runnable` variables, then add the variables to the list instead of the lambda directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently [target typing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-typing)/[type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) didn't work here (I am not sure why yet) and despite the fact that you declared `List<Runnable>` as result, generic type `Arrays.asList` wasn't able to figure out which functional interface you want to implement.

I am not sure if this will work but you can set generic type of `asList` method to `Runnable` manually. To do it just write

```
List<Runnable> tasks = Arrays.<Runnable>asList(
   ...                     // ^^^^^^^^^^ you need to add this
);
```

Comment: This worked, thank you, but anyway I think this should work with ajc (as it compiles properly with javac, and developer should not bother adopting code to ajc compiler)... Maybe it's worth to open bug on bugtracker?

Comment: If ajc is using standard compiler than it is indeed strange. Maybe it is using its own compiler like Eclipse (Eclipse also complains about not being able to compile `Arrays.asList` without explicitly placing `<Runnable>` there).

Comment: ajc does indeed use the eclipse compiler.

Comment: I raised the eclipse issue https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=437007 to cover this (it is still a problem with Eclipse Luna RC3). As soon as they fix it I will pick up the fix when I rebase AspectJ on that fixed version of JDT.

Comment: so, ajc still gives such an error when I used it as separate aspectJ compiler in IDEA. Any ideas? (I use lib AspectJ1.8.7)